# Get latest n records for each group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models:
topic 
comment

topic has_many comments

How i can get the last 4 comments for each topic?

I tried with this but is very slow:

```
Comment.
      joins("INNER JOIN (SELECT m1.id,m1.topic_id, COUNT(m2.id) as c FROM multimedias as m1 LEFT JOin multimedias as m2 ON 
        m1.topic_id = m2.topic_id  AND m1.id < m2.id 
        WHERE m1.topic_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY m1.id, m1.topic_id HAVING c < 4
        ORDER by m1.topic_id, c desc) as m3 ON m3.id = multimedias.id").
      where([ "multimedias.topic_id IN (?)", topics_id ])
```

Comment: did my answer help here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [last](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-last) method

Answer (score 0):

The `#last` method takes an integer as an argument, so you can just use `Comment.last(4)`

Answer (score 0):

## ActiveRecord::FinderMethods#Last

[#last](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-last) has an optional argument that allows you to specify the last N records, like this:

```
Comment.
      joins("INNER JOIN (SELECT m1.id,m1.topic_id, COUNT(m2.id) as c FROM multimedias as m1 LEFT JOin multimedias as m2 ON 
        m1.topic_id = m2.topic_id  AND m1.id < m2.id 
        WHERE m1.topic_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY m1.id, m1.topic_id HAVING c < 4
        ORDER by m1.topic_id, c desc) as m3 ON m3.id = multimedias.id").
      where([ "multimedias.topic_id IN (?)", topics_id ]).
      last(4)
```